# How to use ArcPy SearchCursor, with a where clause, to return string formatted response with values

Tags: arcpy, cursor, statistics

I am using an ArcPy Search Cursor to return the rows of a specified field within a shapefile.
The for loop iterates through the feature class and returns the value of the rows in a formatted string as show below.

Code:

```
fields = ['crops_2020','acreage']
fc =r'C:\geodata\Agricultural_Land_Use_-_2020_Update.shp'
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print("The crop {0} had {1:,} acres gown in 2020".format(row[0],row[1]))
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Question:**
As of now my code just returns each row of the field 'crop_2020' and the associated acreage value. So if there is 20 'tropical fruit' rows for example, the script prints out this formatted text 20 times with a different acreage for each instance of the feature.
What I am trying to figure out is how to return a formatted text string like the one above that returns the **Total** or **Sum** of the acreage per each type of crop.  The types of crops are stored within the 'crops_2020' field and the acre amounts are stored in the 'acreage' field.

Comment: Check out the 'Summary Statistics' tool (or arcpy equivalent).  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm

Comment: This is, in essence, a question on how to use Python.  The cursor returns a list of lists. All you need to do is manage some dictionaries inside the `for` loop. Note that, despite the mention of a WHERE clause in the title, your code does not include one.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @timlohnes answer, but using a dictionary for all crop types, instead of a series of hard-coded scalar variables for each crop type.

```
cropDict = {}

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
    if row[0] in cropDict:
      cropDict[row[0]] += row[1]
    else:
      cropDict[row[0]] = row[1]

for crop in cropDict:
  print("The crop {} had {} acres grown in 2020".format(crop, cropDict[crop]))
```

(Untested - written off the top of my head.)

Or as @bix0012 commented, you could make it even simpler by using a defaultdict instead of a simple dict:

```
cropDict = defaultdict(float)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
    cropDict[row[0]] += row[1]

for crop in cropDict:
  print("The crop {} had {} acres grown in 2020".format(crop, cropDict[crop]))
```

(I've replaced "gown" with "grown", assuming it was a typo.)

Comment: It worked! Thank you a bunch!!

Comment: If one is going to use a dict, why not go with a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and get rid of an if/else block.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this. Add up all the values for different crops, report it out at the end.

I left out the format {} bits as I'm not familiar with that. Tried using brackets and index. May work as is or redo with {} and format if that is how you access values.

```
diversifiedSum = 0
pastureSum = 0

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
    if (row[0] = "Diversified"):
      diversifiedSum += row[1]
    if (row[0] = "Pasture"):
      pastureSum += row[1]

print("The crop Diversified had" + diversifiedSum + "acres gown in 2020")
print("The crop Pasture had" + pastureSum + "acres gown in 2020")
```

Comment: Rather than hard-coded crops values (such as "diversified..." and "pasture", when you do not know if there may be other values, it would be preferable to use a dictionary rather than two hard coded variables.  Eg, `cropDict[row[0]] += row[1]`, etc.

Comment: @SonofaBeach, How would you implement the ```cropDict[row[0]] += row[1]``` into the above code to return the other values.  You are right there are multiple values for crop type, and I want to sum up the total amount acres for each crop type.  Would I have to add in ```cropDict[row[0]] += row[1]``` as a conditional statement within the for loop?